# Haskell how to count occurance of an element in a list recursively?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to recursively count how many times a given element (number) appears in a list.

For example, `equals 2 [1,2,3,2,1,2,3]` should return 3 for the number of times 2 appears in the list.

**What i've done so far:**

```
equals :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Int

equals n [] = 0

equals n (x:xs) =

    if equals n == x
        then 1 + equals n xs
        else equals xs
```

Comment: you can use `foldl` for that does it have to be recursive ?

Comment: Yeah it has to be done recursively. I'm trying to get better at recursion for upcoming tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are nearly there. Just keep in mind when you want to call your function and remember to give it all required arguments.

```
equals :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Int

equals n [] = 0

equals n (x:xs)
    | n == x = 1 + equals n xs
    | otherwise = equals n xs
```

Answer (score 3):

You basically have the solution. There's just a few minor typos to squash.

```
equals :: Integer -> [Integer] -> Int
equals n [] = 0
equals n (x:xs) =
    if n == x then
        1 + equals n xs
    else
        equals n xs
```

In particular, whenever you call `equals`, you need to pass it two parameters. So your recursive call should generally look like `equals n xs`, not `equals xs`. Similarly, your comparison between `n` and `x` is just that: a comparison. It needn't itself make a recursive call, so it only needs to look like `n == x`.